# how to access primefaces datatable row css?

Tags: primefaces, themes, skinning

How can acces row css for multiple colored rows?

I try use :

```
.redRow .ui-datatable-even, ui-datatable-odd {
   background-color: red;
}

.blueRow .ui-datable-even, ui-datatable-odd{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

but it doesnt work, because primefaces theme override this. How to do something like this?

Comment: post your xhtml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your css is loaded after the primefaces css, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8774997/2020834).

Comment: i try this and also  <f:facet name="last"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/myCss.css" /> </f:facet>  ,but it doesnt work.. it seems that theme override all...

Answer (score -1):

In your component include the encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None to access the elements inside the datatable using css selectors.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: The Q is about PrimeFaces, your answer is about angular? No relation to the Q

Comment: Right! My bad. Not deleting my answer for those using Angular and PrimeFaces at the same time :)

Comment: Still then, I fail to see how, in a very unlikely combination, this a solution to the PrimeFaces components css.

Comment: I encountered this kind of problem while using Angular 2. And like OP said that primefaces theme overrides the styles on his css. This solved my problem. If this is unlikely to be considered a solution for this question, just tell me and I will delete my answer. Thanks cheers!